# XSLT: Trouble combining elements from different nodes in one xsl:for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, filemaker

I need to transform something like the following (snippet from a FileMaker FMPXMLRESULT export)

```
<ROW>
   <COL>
      <DATA>A</DATA>
      <DATA>B</DATA>
      <DATA>C</DATA>
   </COL>
   <COL>
      <DATA>1</DATA>
      <DATA>2</DATA>
      <DATA>3</DATA>
   </COL>
</ROW>
```

into an xls.file, where the corresponding DATA elements are put in separate cells next to each other.

Using the following code

```
<xsl:for-each select="FMP:COL[1]/FMP:DATA">
    <xsl:variable name="p"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="../../FMP:COL[2]/FMP:DATA[$p]"/>
        </Data>
    </Cell>
</xsl:for-each>
```

only returns

A 1

B 1

C 1

instead

A 1

B 2

C 3

and I don't know why...

Any help is highly appreciated!

best
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're setting the value of `$p` by using `<xsl:value-of>`, it is going to be treated as a string value when `FMP:DATA[$p]` is evaluated. Since a non-empty string is "truthy", the first `FMP:DATA` element will always be selected.

Instead, just use the `select` attribute when you're setting `p`'s value:

```
<xsl:variable name="p" select="position()" />
```

this will cause it to be correctly treated as a number.